# .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I am unable to install the .NET Framework 3.5 on my Windows 10 box. I tried:

- enabling it through Programs and Features.
- enabling and installing through DISM.
- SFC /scannow

No success. Mostly I get error code 0x800736B3 saying, "The referenced assembly is not installed on your system". Sometimes I get Error 14003. I obviously need .NET due to many apps needing it to run. This is a brand new system. What should I try next?

Comment: Seems to be required. A lot of apps need it and start the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Please proceed with caution as your results may vary:
Look for [.Net Cleanup Utility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx).

I will be honest, have not used under Windows 10.  However, I have had good luck with this application cleaning up old traces of .Net, so you can start afresh with net .Net Install(s).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the [executable installation file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21) from microsoft?

If the NetFX installation files are not under C:\sources\SxS on your installed system, or under /sources/WinSxS in your installation media, you will need to find and download the `microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab` file from Microsoft if you can find it, or from another .iso file which you can downlaod through Media Creation Tool. You can then install it through DISM like this:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:c:\KBnumber.cab
```

If this doesn't work, some people mention using these 2 commands - although I suspect you shouldn't need them if your Windows is freshly installed:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

Comment: This is a 5-year old thread. The issue existed when Windows 10 was freshly out and not yet compatible with other Microsoft products. This is no longer an active problem.

Comment: I've had very similar problems not so long ago that I solved with what I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Programs and Features in the Control Panel, then click on "Turn Windows features on or off".  In the Windows Features dialog, just check the box for .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: I found out that it's more tricky in the Fall Creators Update.  If that's your version, then do this:  insert (or mount) the installation disc, and then enter this command in an elevated command prompt: DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:D:\sources\sxs (assuming D: is the drive where the installation media is).